# Speeding-up multiple conditions inside a loop

Tags: python, language-lawyer

Consider some code that reads:

```
def transformer(item, conditions, transforms):
    for item in items:
        if conditions[0]():
            item = transforms[0](item)
        if conditions[1]():
            item = transforms[1](item)
        if conditions[2]():
            item = transforms[2](item)
        # ...
        yield item
```

since the condition is global, there is no need to actually have an `if` inside the looping, so a faster and horrifically unreadable alternative is:

```
def transformer_fast(item, conditions, transforms):
    if not conditions[0]() and not conditions[1]() and not conditions[2]():
        for item in items:
            yield item
    elif conditions[0]() and not conditions[1]() and not conditions[2]():
        for item in items:
            yield transforms[0](item)
    elif not conditions[0]() and conditions[1]() and not conditions[2]():
        for item in items:
            yield transforms[1](item)
    elif not conditions[0]() and not conditions[1]() and conditions[2]():
        for item in items:
            yield transforms[2](item)
    # elif ... (all possible combinations of conditions and transforms)
```

Is there an alternative approach that would retain readability but avoids performing the checks inside the loop?

In C, C++, etc. this seems to be a job for the preprocessor.

In LISP, OCaml, Julia (?) this would be done by dynamically creating the appropriate code.

What about Python?

Answer (score 1):

Python has first-class functions so I'd do it this way:

```
def transformer(item, conditions, transforms):
    for cond, tran in zip(conditions, transforms):
        if cond():
            break # tran is set correctly now
    for item in items:
        yield tran(item)
```

Or more concisely:

```
def transformer(item, conditions, transforms):
    for cond, tran in zip(conditions, transforms):
        if cond():
            return map(tran, items)
```

You may need to adjust slightly as your two examples don't behave exactly the same way (and in that spirit, neither do mine!).

Comment: Perhaps it was too much hidden in the `...` but the second code is meant to cover all possible cases, including the *no transform* and the *multiple transform* cases. This approach would require `tran` to contemplate the `lambda x: x` case which is probably going to eat up any speed gain that you would get by avoiding the conditional in the loop.

Comment: @norok2: I see.  Well, if you're serious about speeding this up you'll probably have to use Numba or Cython or compile a C++ module anyway, so in a way it doesn't matter.